# kubernetes - can not create deployment correctly

Tags: kubernetes

I create a `deployment.yaml` to create deployment of kubernetes.

Here is my tries:

`apiVersion: apps/v1`

get `error: unable to recognize "./slate-master/deployment.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1"`

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1` and `apiVersion: apps/v1beta1`

both of them, get `Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "./slate-master/deployment.yaml": Deployment in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: v1beta1.Deployment: ...`

here is my kubernetes version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.2", GitCommit:"81753b10df112992bf51bbc2c2f85208aad78335", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-12T04:12:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.7", GitCommit:"b30876a5539f09684ff9fde266fda10b37738c9c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-01-16T21:52:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

So, why kubernetes create deployment failed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `apiVersion: apps/v1` by:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
```

Comment: `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1` and `apiVersion: apps/v1beta1`, both of them throw error

Comment: can you paste your deployment.yaml?

Comment: I figure out there is a syntax error in my `deployment.yaml` file. the `env` value must be String, can not be Number

Answer (score 7):

Check in "env" section, for apiVersion:

```
apps/v1
apps/v1beta1
apps/v1beta2
```

All the env variables should be a string, add the `quote`: e.g

```
- name: POSTGRES_PORT
  value: {{ .Values.db.env.POSTGRES_PORT | quote }}
```